# Question tagged as (maybe) a duplicate

Tags: support

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/q/681143/77149). A note of a type I'm not familiar with now appears at the top:

> **This question may already have an answer here:**
>   [How do I mask the Firefox browser signature?](https://superuser.com/questions/80057/how-do-i-mask-the-firefox-browser-signature) *4 answers*

I didn't notice anything about it being closed as a duplicate, and in fact as stated in the questions and comments it is *not* an answer to this question. How can I get this notice removed?

Comment: I don't see the note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user flagged your question and recommended it be closed as a duplicate. The user later deleted their comment. The question is now in the close vote review queue, but did not get any "real" close vote yet.

The notice is only shown to you in order to alert you of the possible duplicate. It's there so you can edit your question and explain how the duplicate question does not answer yours—if that's the case.

If it ends up being closed, you could flag it for attention to have a moderator check it out. Until then, I wouldn't worry about it.